# What are mathematical functions used to draw the 2 bottom <Chi-Squared> graphes?

Tags: graphing-functions, chi-squared

On MathWorld, at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Chi-SquaredDistribution.html

you can see 4 graphes.

[image]

I have no problem to understand what represent the 2 top graphes.

But I don't understand what represent the 2 bottom graphes. I regret that label of Y axe is, for me, not readable !

What are the functions used to draw these 2 graphes ?

Comment: I believe the label on the $y$-axis is "$r$". So these are visualizing the same functions as the upper graphs, just as a function of $x$ and $r$ simultaneously.